# Mapreduce Text file sort

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Can we sort each line of a text file alphabetically. Is it possible to write a java code in mapreduce format?

for example:

```
 input : it is a lion
         what is her name
         that is crazy

output: it is a lion
        that is crazy
        what is her name
```

Comment: there's only one line in that example. can you expand on what you mean by "alphabetically"? Do you mean the first letter of each line? And if so, can you give us a better example of the output?

Comment: ohh input has three line starts with: 1st-It is a lion, 2nd-what is her name, 3rd-That is crazy. output is 1st-It is a lion, 3rd-That is crazy, 2nd-What is her name.. it should sort with the first letter of each line in a text file.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Do some research on the shuffle/sort phase between map and reduce.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is first create your file object, a File() object. Then use a bufferReader to read each line (look up the documentation for this object, it's pretty self explanatory). You're going to be using the .readLine() method so it will give you an iterator through each line. You then want to store each line in a hashmap where your keys are the first letter of each line and the values are a list of any line you find with that letter.

When you're done, create a StringBuilder object and add each line in alphabetical order.

Comment: He wants to do this using Hadoop and MapReduce... completely different

Answer (score 0):

You need a to write a Driver code with no Mapper class and no Reducer class. The in-built default IdentityMapper and IdentityReducer will do the job for you.